# Using a non-default attribute in path helpers, instead of :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, key

## What I have

I now have a route like

```
get 'book/:id' => 'books#show', as: :book
```

The code to create that URL is:

```
book_path @book
```

In the controller:

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
```

So far so good. Now, this id is obviously the internal ActiveRecord or database primary key.

## What I want

Instead, I would (in this ficticious example) use the ISBN instead. I could do this like so:

```
get 'book/:isbn' => 'books#show', as: :book
book_path(isbn: @book.isbn)
@book = Book.find_by(isbn: params[:isbn])
```

This is a bit verbose; I want the convention "isbn" for this model in the whole application, and nobody should need to care about it, ever. So, I want my 3 lines to look like this:

```
get 'book/:isbn' => 'books#show', as: :book
book_path @book    # (!)
@book = Book.find(params[:isbn])    # (!)
```

Is it possible to configure the route so that my wish comes true? Obviously, this should automatically work *everywhere*, at the very least for GET requests where the user sees the ISBN in the URL.

In case it matters, the `#isbn` attribute is not a primary key in the usual sense, but it is guaranteed that there is only ever one record with a particular ISBN in the table. So at least this part of the Primary Key contract is fulfilled.

Comment: Have you checked [to_param](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/to_param) method ?

Comment: I have not! Thank you, that works great, and solves the more pressing problem of the two. In hindsight, I guess I prefer `#find` so stick to the internal ID, anyways. If you create a mini-answer, you'll get my acceptance.

Comment: @AnoE, thanks for the question,it helped me a lot with Sajan's answer! You might think about accepting Sajan's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override the Rails default `:id` parameter, you can use `to_param` method:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    isbn
  end
end
```

And in controller:

```
book = Book.find_by(isbn: '123456')
```

If you don't have any problem with using any gem for it, then I suggest you should give a look to [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart) Gem. This does a good job in such case.

Comment: Saw this a little late due to a comment from somebody; accepting better late than never. You might mention https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param , it includes some very interesting "features" and extensions to the concept.

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb`, use match to match `/book/:isbn` to `book#show`

```
match '/book/:isbn' => 'book#show', via: :get, as: :show_book
```

In your book.rb, you can override the find method in order find based on isbn instead of id. Something along the lines of:

```
def self.find(*args)
    c = Book.select("id").find_by(name: args[0])
    args[0] = c.id
    super(args)
end
```

This will first find by `isbn` and then using the `id`, it will call the *original* find method. (I have not test this, you will have to modify it to make it work with multiple `isbn`s)

But I am not sure if this is recommended and what caveats it will present.

Instead, why don't you use `find_by_isbn[params[:isbn]]`? It is more readable than `find_by(:isbn, params[:isbn])`.